# How to Change Record Source with VBA in MS Access Report Macro

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

All,

In MS Access 2010, I have a table (Today's Settled Jrnls) that is linked to a report. I run the VBA code below to export the report to a pdf on a shared drive.

```
Public Function exporttopdf()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim MyFileName As String
Dim mypath As String
Dim temp As String

mypath = "S:\Dan\" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & "\"

If Dir(mypath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir mypath

Set db = CurrentDb()

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT distinct [Settlement No] FROM [Today's Settled Jrnls]", dbOpenDynaset)

Do While Not rs.EOF

temp = rs("[Settlement No]")
MyFileName = rs("[Settlement No]") & ".PDF"



DoCmd.OpenReport "Settlement Report", acViewReport, , "[Settlement No]='" & temp & "'"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, mypath & MyFileName
DoCmd.Close acReport, "Settlement Report"
rs.MoveNext

Loop

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

This works but I'd like to change the [Today's Settled Jrnls] table to a different table [New Jrnls]. The new table is has the exact same columns and setup. However, when I change the table in the select statement above, the code runs but the report is blank. I assume this is because the report (Settlement Report) is still linked to the old table. Do you know how I can link the report to the new table with VBA?

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add a `RecordSource` call to point to new table after first opening report:

```
' OPEN REPORT
DoCmd.OpenReport "Settlement Report", acViewReport
' ADJUST SOURCE
Reports![Settlement Report].Report.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM [New Jrnls]"

' FILTER AND OUTPUT
DoCmd.OpenReport "Settlement Report", acViewReport, , "[Settlement No]='" & temp & "'"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, mypath & MyFileName
DoCmd.Close acReport, "Settlement Report"
```

Comment: Great! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set the Reports recordsource property to a SQL String or bind it to the table

You can even use may of the events like open to set

```
Me.RecordSource ="SELECT * FROM TBL"
```

[image]

Here check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.report.recordsource

For Parfat:

[image]

Comment: Code likely is not behind report to have access for `Me.RecordSource`. Use absolute reference.

Comment: @Parfait IDK it seems to have it to me